# PHP Set Roblox Avatar to Image

Tags: php, roblox

I've been trying to figure this out for like 3 hours and am not getting anywhere. I'm trying to set the img src in the avatar div to the Roblox user's avatar URL with this endpoint https://thumbnails.roblox.com/v1/users/avatar-bust?userIds=3102777127&size=150x150&format=Png&isCircular=true but it requires usernames and my data is usernames so we have to use this endpoint to get IDs https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username=VOICECHAT22983. I have been trying a bunch of different stuff and nothing is working and just getting a bunch of errors.

This is how the data looks:

```
brenda12322323
eunaodoaisnudhnac
Lovesroblox1334
Cho5963
Sinmin191
vikaa_qwixxk
yourfav_stepsister
SnipesG0D
```

This is the PHP Code

```
<?php
$lines = file('../txt/names.txt');
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    echo '<div class="avatar">
        <img src="'.$avatar.'" alt="">
        <h1>' . $line . '</h1>
        <a href="https://www.roblox.com/users/'.$id.'/profile">Profile</a>
    </div>';
}
?>
```

I'm trying to set the $id variable as the user's ID and the avatar variable as the image URL

Answer (score 1):

You need to get all the IDs first from the `get-by-username` endpoint, pass those into the avatars endpoint, then put the data back together:

```
<?php

/*

Question Author: cdnAshton
Question Answerer: Jacob Mulquin
Question: PHP Set Roblox Avatar to Image
URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74977675/php-set-roblox-avatar-to-image
Tags: php, roblox

*/

function get_id_by_username($name)
{
    $url = 'https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username=' . $name;
    echo 'getting ' . $url . PHP_EOL;
    return json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
}

function get_avatar_urls($ids)
{
    $ids_param = implode(',', $ids);
    $url = 'https://thumbnails.roblox.com/v1/users/avatar-bust?userIds='.$ids_param.'&size=150x150&format=Png&isCircular=true';
    return json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
}

if (!file_exists('users.json')) {
    $names = file('names.txt');
    $users = [];
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        $name = trim($name);
        $id = get_id_by_username($name);
        $users[$id['Id']] = $id;
        sleep(15); // Needed otherwise you will hit API rate-limits
    }

    file_put_contents('users.json', json_encode($ids, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)); 
} else {

    $users = json_decode(file_get_contents('users.json'), true);

    $ids = [];
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $ids[] = $user['Id'];
    }
    $avatars = get_avatar_urls($ids);

    foreach ($avatars['data'] as $avatar) {
        $users[$avatar['targetId']]['AvatarUri'] = $avatar['imageUrl'];
    }

    file_put_contents('users.json', json_encode($users, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)); 
}
```

The script is executed twice, the first time it will read the names from `names.txt`, and get the IDS, saving into a `users.json` file. Then when you execute it again, it will get the IDs from the JSON file, then call the avatars and then merge it back together. The result is a JSON file like so:

```
{
    "3528175625": {
        "Id": 3528175625,
        "Username": "brenda12322323",
        "AvatarUri": "https:\/\/tr.rbxcdn.com\/3c195f46b44d37aa250c0d7c6ae41ded\/150\/150\/AvatarBust\/Png\/isCircular",
        "AvatarFinal": false,
        "IsOnline": false
    },
    "4028593775": {
        "Id": 4028593775,
        "Username": "eunaodoaisnudhnac",
        "AvatarUri": "https:\/\/tr.rbxcdn.com\/0fc96af99739e29c780af459db6c2bd8\/150\/150\/AvatarBust\/Png\/isCircular",
        "AvatarFinal": false,
        "IsOnline": false
    }
}
```

Then to output this information on a webpage:

```
$users = json_decode(file_get_contents('users.json'), true);

foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo '<div class="avatar">
    <img src="'.$user['AvatarUri'].'" alt="">
    <h1>' . $user['Username'] . '</h1>
    <a href="https://www.roblox.com/users/'.$user['Id'].'/profile">Profile</a>
    </div>';
}
```

Gives you something like this:
[image: Roblox usernames and profile pictures]

Comment: Why when I use that code, and going to the site it adds some random unfinished json?
`"-766791671": {
        "AvatarUri": "https:\/\/tr.rbxcdn.com\/3c195f46b44d37aa250c0d7c6ae41ded\/150\/150\/AvatarBust\/Png\/isCircular"
    },
    "-266373521": {
        "AvatarUri": "https:\/\/tr.rbxcdn.com\/0fc96af99739e29c780af459db6c2bd8\/150\/150\/AvatarBust\/Png\/isCircular"
    }`

Comment: The code you run to get the avatars should not be in the same script you use to output them. The code also has no error checking if the username does not exist